# Scrolling Dataset with down arrow hangs its display

Tags: dataset, display

Update : same in v **11.3.0** (OSX) (so bad, it just froze completly the Front End and I had to kill by hand ... and I lost some work !!! Be careful)

---

It's rather an annoying problem i've got many times now and which is reproducible (mma **v11.2.0**) even for a small dataset:

```
Dataset@Table[i, {i, 220}]
```

[image]

When **for the first time** I try to **scroll** the dataset, if I use the down arrow

[image]

instead of the big scrolling grey bar, the display hangs and i am invited to disable the dynamic updating

[image]

If I click "Continue" the message returns, and there is no other choice than to disable dynamics. With big notebooks and datasets it even crashed the whole session ...

The only workaround I've found, is to scroll first using the scrollbar, then the use of the down arrow causes no problem ... but you easily forget.

Comment: I could never make any real use of `Dataset`. Let's hope WRI fixes some of the old implementation weaknesses (like Dataset and "MouseExited" and spinning wheels of the notebook FrontEnd) soon.

Comment: @RolfMertig Just interested to know : what do you use instead of `Dataset`? List of associations ?

Comment: yes. Or Grid. Or I write my own custom function to handle larger data display.